# RestTemplate upload image file

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I need to create RestTemplate request, which will send image to upload by PHP application.

My code is:

```
Resource resource = new FileSystemResource("/Users/user/Documents/MG_0599.jpg");
MultiValueMap<String, Object> parts = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
    parts.add("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
    parts.add("file", resource);
    parts.add("id_product", productId);

ResponseEntity<String> response = cookieRestTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class, parts);
```

After start this app, PHP server send me information, that file is empty.

I was thinking, that problem is by PHP site, but i've installed POSTER plugin for Firefox, and i made GET request onto this same URL, but the file to upload, i've selected normaly like in web form (popup system window to select file).
After this PHP program uploaded file without any problem.

I think, that problem is maybe with this, that i'm sending resource as value of param name:

```
parts.add("file", resource);
```

And on the POSTER plugin, i just select file from my file system ?

Can you help me ?

Comment: i've updated description

Comment: Ok, but everywhere i found informations, that i should upload file like this. Do you have any other solution ? I can add something to header, but what ?

Answer (score 9):

You aren't using the `RestTemplate` correctly. You are using the following method

```
public <T> ResponseEntity<T> getForEntity(String url, Class<T> responseType, Map<String, ?> urlVariables)
```

So you see your `MultiValueMap` is going to be used as a source for URL variables which you don't actually seem to have. There are no request parameters sent in the request.

You won't actually be able to upload a file with any of the `getForX` methods.

You will have to use one of the `exchange` methods. For example

```
Resource resource = new FileSystemResource(
            "/Users/user/Documents/MG_0599.jpg");
MultiValueMap<String, Object> parts = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
parts.add("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
parts.add("file", resource);
parts.add("id_product", productId);

restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET,
            new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(parts),
            String.class); // make sure to use the generic type argument
```

Note, that it is very uncommon to do a file upload with a `GET` request.

Comment: I was testing your version of request, but exchange request doesn't pass to PHP controller. I don't know why, but i get 500 error. GetForEntity works fine, but doesn't send image :/

Comment: @llkar 500 is a server side error. Maybe it's having hard time receiving the file. Do you have a max file upload size?

Comment: No it's not size limit, file has 300KB. Do you know how to simulate exchange request in POSTER tool to firefox ?

Comment: @Ilkar The exchange method in this case is simply sending a GET request with a `multipart` content-type.